# Understanding flow of current from diagram using AND gate

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I have a question about current flow in the diagrams below, which are from my textbook. I'm in a class called "digital logic" and we are using a zyBooks.com textbook, and it's HORRID, and we are getting no help from the professor right now.

My question is why current flows from the top in the first image, and then it flows from ground in the second image? All the book ever says is that it flows from a point of high-voltage to a point of low-voltage.

[image: Flow from top]
[image: Flow from ground]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no current flow because these are CMOS gates, so the red arrows do not resemble flow of current at all. You can just think the red arrows to show the path of the connection, i.e. which FET is turned on like a switch.

Comment: I don't know what CMOS gates are. They only tell us what nMOS and pMOS transistors are. Thinking about the arrows as a path for connection does help though. The arrows are very deceiving. Again...this textbook, IMO, is garbage. Thank you for clearing it up for me.

Comment: In case you have not noticed, the diagrams are AND logic gates, constructed of NMOS and PMOS transistors, which means it is a CMOS AND logic gate.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Don't think of the red lines and arrows as current flow - think of them as a low impedance path. The arrows point towards the destination object i.e. in the case above, the "a" or "b" lines being zero would "activate" either of the two parallel P channel MOSFETs that would then pass logic 1 through to the output stage: -

[image]

And, regarding the MOSFETs, these are the symbols: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/E-Book/C4_DigitalLogic.htm).

Sure, the arrows are deceptive but, like you said in your own words: -

> *it's HORRID*

And if it's meant to indicate current flow, then it's horrid so, think of it as a low impedance path.

Comment: It doesn't ever indicate what the red arrows are. I always just assumed it was current flow. As you said, they are deceiving. Thank you for your input and clarifying things for me.

Answer (score 0):

The mosfets with the small circles are P-channel mosfets, they pass current when there gate is pulled low a certain amount relative to there source pin, in this example just know that pulling it low makes it act like a closed switch

The others are N-channel mosfets, they pass current when there gate is pulled high a certain amount.

So for you it might be best to imagine each of those mosfets as a light switch, and depending on if the gate is high or low, they are switched on or off.

The diagrams shown are more what is currently connected by closed switches, so for the top image, both of the p-mosfets would be switched on, meaning the output node would be held to the top input (normally a voltage supply for the chip), this in turn activates the n-mosfet on the output, connecting it to ground

Comment: Thank you for your time and input, Reroute. Really helps.